# traversing a singly linked list in C++

Tags: c++, pointers, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I was wondering if it is possible to traverse a linked list like this:

```
currentNode = randomNode;//where randomNode may or may not = firstNode
prevNode = firstNode;
while(prevNode != currentNode && prevNode->link != currentNode)
{
    prevNode = prevNode->link;
}
```

Is it possible to do this in C++ when I am trying to find the node before currentNode in a singly linked list?

I trying to implement something like this in a console app for a school assignment so assume that I can't use anything fancy like the boost libraries/list/anything that makes life easier, etc. So basically, I have only fairly primitive datatypes and libraries at my disposal.

Comment: Why "wonder" if you can just try it and see how (and if) it works? I don't see any problems here, assuming that you always have at least one node, and that `randomNode` is guaranteed to be a valid node in the list (so you will never run "off the end").

Comment: What is it that you exactly want to do? Search for a node in the linked list?

Comment: The while condition looks a bit strange...why test for prevNode != currentNode ?  Also, can the list be empty?  Can it happen that currentNode is not present in the list?

Comment: @Pavel: It's in my code already but I'm not in a place where I can test at easily yet. I figured I would check here to see if it makes logical sense and is at least possible the real question I at the heart of it all is whether or not this code is kosher as far as <code>prevNode = prevNode->link;</code> goes. 

@Ashwin: I s'pose you could call it searching, but I plan I using this loop to help me insert a new node between two nodes. 

@Jim: I'm testing for that in case <code>randomNode</code> is equal to <code>firdtNode</code> in which case there would be no node before it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You might want to make sure that prevNode->link is not a null reference either, in case currentNode is not actually linked.

Comment: If currentNode is guaranteed to be in the list (which from the description it seems to be), the loop will always terminate before the end of the list.

Answer (score 1):

That should work just fine. Have you tried it yet?

Comment: yes and no. it's in my code but there are other parts missing and I haven't worked on it for a few days so not everything is "hooked up" yet

Answer (score 1):

The code looks fine, but I would suggest a minor change to your `while` condition

```
while(prevNode != currentNode && prevNode != NULL)
```

For two reasons

- Your code, as currently stated, could stop if the node we are looking for is pointed to by either `prevNode` or `prevNode->link` (and therefore we will have no idea which particular one of the two points to `currentNode` -- if we wanted to know, we would have to check with an `if` condition). With the change above, the target node is guaranteed to be stored in `prevNode` (if at all -- see next point).
- For safety's sake, it would be good to check that `prevNode` is not `NULL`. However, as Pavel mentions, this test is unnecessary if `currentNode` is guaranteed to be in the list.

---

**Edit in response to comment**

Given that you don't need to know whether `currentNode` is in `prevNode` or `prevNode->link`, and since you want to stop (if possible) on `currentNode == prevNode->link`, then your original `while` is fine. However...

> there is an if statement higher up in
>   the code that prevents
>   `prevNode` from being null
>   already

It seems like you're missing the point of why you should check for `NULL`. Yes, that's good you check it before, but the reason why we have the `NULL` check in the loop is in the case where `currentNode` is *not* in the list, so you eventually reach the last node. Presumably (if you do this like most other linked lists) the value of `link` for your last node is `NULL`. If so, your current code will eventually end up calling `NULL->link` which of course will crash your program. That's why you should still check for `NULL`

```
while(prevNode != NULL && prevNode != currentNode && prevNode->link!=currentNode)
```

If you're *absolutely sure* that `currentNode` will be in the list, then I *guess* that check is also unnecessary, but it really is a good habit to get into.

Comment: The reason I have the condition that way because there is an if statement higher up in the code that prevents <code>prevNode</code> from being null already so basically I want to make sure that <code>prevNode</code> is equal to current Node or the node before <code>currentNode</code> which ever is first.

Answer (score 1):

That code will traverse some part of your list, but which part depends on which way your list is linked.  If it goes from head->tail (read: head node links to a node which links towards tail) then you would traverse your list starting from the random location to the tail.  If the links are head<-tail then you would traverse from the random location to the head.  In either case, you would not touch all the nodes in the list.

All of the above assumes some link list as such:

```
[head]<->[0...N Nodes]<->[Tail]
```

The links could be either way.

Also, you could link the head and tail nodes and create a circularly linked list.  In that scenario, it is possible to visit all nodes by simply traversing until you are back to your original node.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you consider all of the possible edge cases:

- What happens `randomNode` equals `firstNode`?  What do you return?  What *should* you return?
- What happens when `randomNode` is the last node in the list?
- What happens when `randomNode` is `NULL`?
- What happens when `randomNode` is not in the list?

Now, not all of these cases may be applicable, depending on if you know anything about `randomNode`, and some of these may be trivial.  But they are all worth thinking about.

If you consider all of these very carefully, there is a simple and elegant solution that handles them all.

Answer (score 0):

You can even have:

```
while (prevNode && prevNode != currentNode)
    prevNode = prevNode->link;
```

But what you have looks fine.

Answer (score 0):

A small thing I'd change with the code as posted (aside from the possibility discussed in other answers of running off the end of the list if currentNode isn't on the list or other error handling) is that when the while loop is done you don't know if `prevNode` or `prevNode->link` points to `currentNode`.  This isn't a huge problem (since you can easily test for it), but it seems to me that it's best to test for this special case situation before the search, so it's clear that it's a special case.